# Cannot inject $ionicHistory into my angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I am trying to utilize $ionicHistory.goBack() in a Controller in my Angularjs/Ionic app. When I try and inject it into my controller as below

```
app.controller('ClockInController', function($scope, $http, JobData, Data, $rootScope, $interval, $ionicHistory)
```

and I run the app I get the error below:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ionicHistoryProvider <- $ionicHistory http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24ionicHistoryProvider%20%3C-%20%24ionicHistory, http://localhost:8100/vendors/onsen/js/angular/angular.js, Line: 4116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionicModuleOrWhatever'])
.controller('ClockInController', ['$ionicHistory', function ($ionicHistory) {
    // Do something with $ionicHistory
}]);
```

I figured this out with the link you provided: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24ionicHistoryProvider%20%3C-%20%24ionicHistory. Documentation can be a bit dense but it was the first line

update: you mentioned you copied the code from github, I found your issue. Instead of cloning you must have copied the file you thought you were supposed to - but you copied the [wrong file](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/service/history.js).

Due to your error `Uncaught ReferenceError: IonicModule is not defined, localhost:8100/js/history.js, Line: 19` -- That file has The following lines 19&20:

```
IonicModule
.factory('$ionicHistory', [
```

To me, this looks like coffeescript, which is not compiled. **The file you copied was not the release version of the file**. You need [this file](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/release/js/ionic.js), instead. The [ionic github project](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic) contains a gulpfile, which means they are using a build tool. Likely you had copied the file that is used to generate the release version of the file, instead of the release version of the file. In projects like this that contain either a gulpfile or gruntfile, check for a `/dist/` directory, a `/dest/` directory, a `release` directory, or a `build/` directory and instead copy the file from there. You can also copy the `.min.js` version of the file if you don't plan on modifying the $ionicHistory source code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I gave this a try but I am still getting the same error. I wonder is there is something that I need to include or install for this. I found a history.js on github with the $ionicHistory code but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Hi Mark, if $ionicHistory is an external module you'll need to perform what's called *dependency injection*. Basically you need to make sure 'myApp' has access to the $ionicHistory module. Two steps to make sure it is required properly: 1) include the history.js file in your index.html after loading angular.js but before loading app.js 2) change the defintion of 'myApp' to  `angular.module('myApp', ['$ionicHistory'])`... [docs for module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), note that $ionicHistory might have a different module name than service name. Also if I helped plz upvote/accept

Comment: Did step 1 and 2 but I am getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: IonicModule is not defined, http://localhost:8100/js/history.js, Line: 19". It is the first bit of code in that file. I copied it directly from Github.

Comment: where on github, what repo

Comment: did you clone from github or copy the file contents?

Comment: I'm confused the file at the link in your update (ionic.js) has no reference to $ionicHistory in it. I copied to my project and included it in the index.html. Then I injected ionicHistory into my controller but it still gives me the unknown provider error.

Comment: ah - try ionic-angular.js https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/release/js/ionic-angular.js

Comment: When I include that in my index.html (<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ionic-angular.js"></script>) I get Uncaught ReferenceError: ionic is not defined, http://localhost:8100/js/ionic-angular.js, Line: 2620

Comment: try includeing ionic, then ionic-angular

Comment: That solved the ionic undefined error but I still get the Unknown provider: $ionicHistoryProvider <- $ionicHistory. I made sure my controller referenced ionicHistory as you show above.

Comment: your controller should reference ionic history but so should your module.

Comment: I add it to the module, i.e.     var app = angular.module('sensationApp', ['onsen.directives', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'angular-carousel', 'google-maps'.ns(), 'appLocalStorage', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ui.map', 'ui.event', 'nvd3', 'ionicHistory']);

Here is the controller
    app.controller('ClockInController', ['$ionicHistory', function($scope, $http, JobData, Data, $rootScope, $interval, $ionicHistory) {
/* Bunch of code */
    }]);

Comment: 2     775760   error    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantia
te module sensationApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionicHistory due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ionicHistory' is not available! You either miss
pelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
 you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/nomod?p0=ionicHistory
    at http://localhost:8100/vendors/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:80:12
    at http://localhost:8100/vendors/onsen/js/angular/