# $ionicHistory is not working even after injecting in the controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

abcApp.controller ( 
               'tgroupCtrl',
                ['$ionicHistory',function($scope,$ionicHistory)
                       {
                         $scope.subheader = "Daily Drills";
                        }
               ]
              );

**The error which I am getting is**

ionic.bundle.js:17696 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ionicHistoryProvider <- $ionicHistory <- Ihistory

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('abcApp', ['ionicModuleOrWhatever'])
.controller('tgroupCtrl', ['$ionicHistory', function ($ionicHistory) {
    // Do something with $ionicHistory
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var abcApp = angular.module('abcApp',['ionic'])
abcApp.controller ( 'tgroupCtrl', ['$ionicHistory',function($scope,$ionicHistory) { $scope.subheader = "Daily Drills"; } ] );
```

**Duplicate**

[Cannot inject $ionicHistory into my angularjs controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837920/cannot-inject-ionichistory-into-my-angularjs-controller)